# four bar linkage coupled.

Tags: coordinate-systems, classical-mechanics

How can I get the point (x,y) at a four bar linkage coupled? The four bar linkage is free until is connected with another fifth bar, then it's not free anymore.

See image below, when the bar FE is connected then the mechanism is fixed, so knowing all the lengths of the bars and coordinates from A,B,F, How to get the point E(x,y) once this fifth bar is coupled?:

[image: four bar linkage with acoplation point]

Any tip how to start?

Comment: "Aclopated" and "aclopation" are not words. Can you rewrite this to be understandable?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the mention of *coupling* in the problem.  There are a few other things that need to be clarified.  I have made the picture visible to expedite discussion.  It seems to me that there are six rigid links (including the three sides of the pink triangle) to which you propose to add a seventh (rather than a fifth) rigid link EF.

Comment: It's true but this is a classical mechanism that quite often is called "fourbar linkage", see link: [link] (https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/6-4-general-fourbar-linkage-configuration-notation-shown-figure-p6-1-link-lengths-coupler--q24880179)

Answer (score 1):

You get a polynomial system from the geometric relations. Determine the angle of the triangle by its point $(c,s)$ on the unit circle, $c^2+s^2=1$. That means the local coordinates of the triangle translate to global coordinates via $C+\pmatrix{c\\s}x+\pmatrix{-s\\c}a$. Then the points are connected via the equations
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{D_x\\D_y} &= \pmatrix{C_x\\C_y}+\pmatrix{c&-s\\s&c}\pmatrix{x_D\\y_D} \\
\pmatrix{E_x\\E_y} &= \pmatrix{C_x\\C_y}+\pmatrix{c&-s\\s&c}\pmatrix{x_E\\y_E} \\
(C_x-A_x)^2+(C_y-A_y)^2&=l_{AC}^2\\
(D_x-B_x)^2+(D_y-B_y)^2&=l_{BD}^2\\
(F_x-E_x)^2+(F_y-E_y)^2&=l_{EF}^2\\
\end{align}
where $(x_D,y_D),(x_E,y_E)$ are the design parameters of the triangle in the angle-zero position, and $l_{AC},l_{BD},l_{EF}$ the lengths of the linkage. These are $8$ equations for the $8$ variables $c,s,C_x,C_y,D_x,D_y,E_x,E_y$. The degrees of the equations, essentially 4 quadratic equations, give a Bezout bound of $16$ solutions. Due to the structure this might be less in actual computations.

Measuring the lengths in the image one can program this system in some CAS, here Magma ([online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)), and solve it.

```
AC:=19; BD:=16; EF:=15; 
Ax:=0; Ay:=0; Bx:=30; By:=0; Fx:=33; Fy:=27; 
xD:=7; xE:=6; yD:=0; yE:=8;
P<Cx,Cy,s,c> := PolynomialRing(Rationals(),4);
Dx := Cx+c*xD-s*yD;
Dy := Cy+s*xD+c*yD;
Ex := Cx+c*xE-s*yE;
Ey := Cy+s*xE+c*yE;
eqns := [ c^2+s^2-1, (Cx-Ax)^2+(Cy-Ay)^2-AC^2, (Dx-Bx)^2+(Dy-By)^2-BD^2, (Fx-Ex)^2+(Fy-Ey)^2-EF^2 ];
eqns:=GroebnerBasis(eqns); eqns;
RR:=RealField(60);
PR<z>:=PolynomialRing(RR);
crts := Roots(Evaluate(eqns[4],[0,0,0,z]));
for rc in [ Re(r[1]) : r in crts | (RR!(1+Im(r[1])) eq 1)] do 
  rCx := Evaluate(-eqns[1],[0,0,0,rc]); 
  rCy := Evaluate(-eqns[2],[0,0,0,rc]);
  rs  := Evaluate(-eqns[3],[0,0,0,rc]);
  "[c,s]=",[rc,rs];
  "C=",[rCx,rCy];
  "D=",[  rCx+rc*xD-rs*yD, rCy+rs*xD+rc*yD];
  "E=",[  rCx+rc*xE-rs*yE, rCy+rs*xE+rc*yE];
end for;
```

giving the solution basis in a univariate representation

```
[
    Cx - 14432169851446728654000000/5191801014443045982521*c^5 + 6661313232418303295256000/305400059673120351913*c^4 - 344560879940427572314392990/5191801014443045982521*c^3 + 29643530141007224152841697/305400059673120351913*c^2 - 
        351171917249443265981900398/5191801014443045982521*c + 278840823389663655039230120/15575403043329137947563,
    Cy - 2584993129060674394448916975900000/37501110413030887604662545667051*c^5 + 310369619334037802774192826019200/37501110413030887604662545667051*c^4 + 110334151073853080090444357018378757/75002220826061775209325091334102*c^3 - 
        306176365574148197298604595354792859/75002220826061775209325091334102*c^2 + 148061781072429761484841313305727010/37501110413030887604662545667051*c - 48375095087854278718671606563698219/37501110413030887604662545667051,
    s - 299904501444837918174000/1916738432567151324491*c^5 + 2341476274178540137175712/1916738432567151324491*c^4 - 710894726963939990058445899/191673843256715132449100*c^3 + 1039926492134194763600163459/191673843256715132449100*c^2 - 
        36310230545435198504884227/9583692162835756622455*c + 28959787323808665177574891/28751076488507269867365,
    c^6 - 459249841/47103875*c^5 + 184381360239781/4748070600000*c^4 - 44100750195001/547854300000*c^3 + 432417076439221/4748070600000*c^2 - 339657464603267/6409895310000*c + 118589060144749/9614842965000
]
```

From the last equation one can see that there are only 6 complex solutions, this should also be the generic number of solutions for any parameter set.

```
[c,s]= [ 0.989684439405989047023683799008623465290796420678386204668705, 0.14326447709621947434448968736051231685801365866322695836 ]
C= [ 14.3734662977301352208542275425509834730410693615805016, 12.42591914459513774813401165305227650735730062461067722022 ]
D= [ 21.30125737357205855002001413561134773007664430632920503268, 13.42877048426867406854543946457586272536339623525326592874 ]
E= [ 19.16545711739631370824041283771862572992173861634500316113, 21.20298152242036697039042016928433813083175394201712860773 ]

[c,s]= [ 0.768813742096953312638710171385170355413562460645114032343627, -0.63947277499740312072900053450613600189859725729402276437 ]
C= [ 12.2002476699512298812111359300276598390921202398232864, 14.56550571699622059354125381291948655312707034481205737774 ]
D= [ 17.58194386462990306968210712972385232698705746433908462641, 10.08919629201439874843825007137653453983688954375389802715 ]
E= [ 21.92891232251217472287540123438776998676227306204615270902, 16.87917900378742837027693197696403338504398648620883305027 ]
```

Two real solutions were found, for angles close to 0° and -30°, the second one should correspond to the image.

Comment: Hi LutzL, I don't understand exactly what is "c" and "s" that defines the angle of the triangle. I think I can solve the equations to get a parametric solution on Matlab, as my target is to implement it on a Excel sheet for testing the mechanism with different lenghts. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: $c=\cos\phi$, $s=\sin\phi$. It makes complications to add transcendental equations to an algebraic system, thus instead of $\phi$ use the point on the unit circle. You can not avoid the 6th degree polynomial and finding its roots, the system is irreducible. I do not know if polynomial roots are easy in Excel. Of course one can program any root-finding method in VBA.

Comment: I will try to get parametric solutions and then choose those have real numbers. I will let you know how it goes... Thanks for your time!

Comment: Just making $B_x$ variable gives a parametric solution that should produce a printout of 3-4 pages. You will probably get easier results implementing a path-following or homotopy approach.